# DC current measurement in a battery cell

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, current-source, battery-chemistry

I want to apply a fixed voltage (around 1.1V) to an electrochemical battery cell in order to remove some oxygen from it due to parasite processes that affects the battery operation.

At the same time, I need to measure accurately the instantaneous current through this cell (avoiding affecting its value) along a period of time (from hours to days). This current changes along time and in a non linear way (due to temperature, liquid pressure, active substances) and it is very difficult to predict its behaviour. To have an idea of the current, a typical value can be 5 mA.

Right now I am using an adjustable power supply with current limit, however its current measurement accuracy is only 10 mA. The setup is really simple, like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Does this way of measuring the current make sense? I have thought also to use a current source instead of the power supply but I am not sure if it makes sense for this kind of load and what can happen.
2. How can I measure this current with accuracy and also avoiding affecting the current value?

Finally, I would also like to send this current measurement to my Arduino so I can do some computations. By the way, the relay of the setup is controlled by this Arduino.

Comment: As you need a fixed voltage, a current source is the wrong tool. Measure the voltage across a current shunt for a more accurate measurement. Look for a PSU with "remote sensing", and connect the sense terminal after the current shunt so that it accurately controls the voltage across the load (compensates for voltage across the shunt).

Comment: @user_1818839 that makes sense. Can you recommend a current shunt for this kind of application? I have never used a current shunt anyways. Regarding the PSU, I will look for it. I will update the thread with all my findings.

Comment: _”centi amperes”_ Please use engineering notation of thousands prefixes. In EE we would call it tens of mA.

Comment: Recommend a current shunt? It's a low value resistor, I'm not going to make a specific recommendation!

Comment: @winny you are right, I have just edited it, sorry!

Comment: @user_1818839 ok. In Spanish we don't have a word for a shunt so that is why I asked. It is clear now!

Comment: No worries! Can you draw a simple block diagram of your proposed setup. It’s fairly clear but the devil is often in the details.

Comment: @winny I have just added the block diagram, let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Is this a one-off test setup or mass production? If the former, it sounds like you need a programmable CC/CV lab power supply which can read low currents well.

Comment: @winny this is a prototype, just the first tests to do some research. I will take a look into that kind of power supply then! Do you know any provider of it? I have a decent budget.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic but here is a broad search for you. Start checking datasheets and check under current accuracy: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/equipment-power-supplies-test-bench/633?s=N4IgjCBcoCwBxVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogDMATAAwUj4wUwBsTA7HSPNRUx5QJwR8A2gF18AB1RQQAZQwBLAHYBzEAF98bRCBSQMOfEUilqlML3zUYVMAisV%2BNISEb9WZKhwpwwMAKxk3r4wYF5aZPxwvOIgUjLy6MpqmiAAtLTQumhYeIQkIP4gouqlQA

Comment: @winny that filter has been very useful, thanks. I will probably go for the 0.1 mA resolution. I am going to have a thought about all of this, discuss with my colleagues and then I will come back here.

Comment: Besides the current measurement (this will be another setup), I would like to apply a fixed voltage of around 1.1V, and I would like to use an IC for this to avoid connecting a PSU and adjusting the voltage. My idea is to use a voltage reference IC. However, I think that a voltage reference provides almost no current, and I really need to provide around 5mA there. Does this mean that I need a voltage regulator instead of a voltage reference?. Also acuraccy will decrease I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The best accuracy of current measurement will provide multimeter (as an ampermeter). There are logging ones (for example APPA505), which can be programmed to store measurements over given period of time. Then these values may be uploaded to a PC via USB.

Ampermeter connected between power supply and the cell will introduce some error to voltage setting (voltage across the cell will differ from voltage given by PSU). As @user_1818839 suggested, the best way to mitigate such error is appropriately connected 'remote sensing' PSU.

Comment: You are right! I have checked with a good amperimeter and accuracy is really high (0.1 mV). Also I have heard that I can use some hall effect sensor to avoid affecting the measurement (like a current clamp).

Comment: @bardulia. yeah, there are a number of options, even with hall sensor! At any given system complexity (cost) there will be a trade between voltage and current measurement accuracy. Hall sensor gives zero voltage error, but I’m not sure about current accuracy.

Comment: That makes sense. First I will probably try with the ampermeter as you suggested. Then If I need more accuracy I will try something with a hall sensor.